# Bypassing Optional Layers for Series of Differences in Graphical Model

Tags: geoprocessing, qgis-modeler

I am working on a graphical model which uses succeeding geoprocessing differences but some layers to subtract are optional, however each step subtracts more depending on the layer.

Example iterative geospatial subtraction:
Area -> Diff1 -> Result1
then feed Diff1 (as input) -> Diff2 -> Result2
... (continue to subtract layers)...
Final result

[image]

Each Diff would take its own optional layer.

Another way to state:
A - B - C = A - (B + C), if you let B or C = 0 you will still feed A into the subtraction process.

As it is, my algorithm appears to depend on the prior layer being completed before I can continue subtracting another layer, but some of these could be optional, such as the layer containing a road, then I don't need to worry about the roads if there aren't any there.

The model will not finish without the optional data layers and building this model another way is not very practical. I would like the input to bypass the subtraction, as if it were subtracting nothing (like in simple arithmetic, you end up with what you start when you subtract zero so you continue with what you got) in the case the layer is optional and keep the input as is, and model for making the geoprocess "difference" optional.

It appears the information about the area is unable to progress forward into the other parts of the main algorithm to check for a layer to compute a difference.

I find my model works well as a whole but does not function with optional cases. IS there conditional branching that will work here? How would I write code for that if it does?